# How to get value of column but not an array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to change my array to number.

This is what I get
 **`"total_amount" => "817450.00"`**

but I only want the **817450.00**

How to change to number but not array.

```
  $total_sale = CtAgent::where('agent_id', $agent_id)
    ->select('total_amount')
    ->orderByDesc('ct_id')
    ->limit('1')
    ->first();
    dd($total_sale);
```

`show number`

Comment: you don't need to use `limit` `first()` returns only one record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $total_sale = CtAgent::where('agent_id', $agent_id)
    ->select('total_amount')
    ->orderByDesc('ct_id')
    ->limit('1')
    ->first()['total_amount'];
```

Comment: Tq bro... i don't know can do like this ->first()['total_amount'];

Comment: Yes you can but @nakov solution is better

Comment: I suppose accessing `total_amount` using `->` operator should work too.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the attribute:

```
  $total_sale = optional(CtAgent::where('agent_id', $agent_id)
    ->select('total_amount')
    ->orderByDesc('ct_id')
    ->limit('1')
    ->first())->total_amount;
    dd($total_sale);
```

Using optional in case the query returns `null` so it won't throw an exception.

Comment: tq.. this was helpful <3

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers will work but here is a different method of doing the same, Which I prefer.

```
$total_sale = CtAgent::where('agent_id', $agent_id)
->orderByDesc('ct_id')
->pluck('total_amount')
->first();
```

& You don't have to handle if no records are found or value is null. ;)